# Script to HUP parent and child process

Tags: grep, freebsd, kill, pid, nohup

I need a shell script to send a HUP to the parent and child processes.

I am using freeBSD with tcsh? #/bin/sh

Somehow, I need to pipe the PID output from pgrep to kill -HUP in a loop in a shell script.

Ultimately I want to run this script as a cron job.

I just don't have the skills yet.

Thanks - Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This isn't a complete answer, but I can't make comments without at least 50 reputation apparently).

First of all, /bin/sh on FreeBSD is a Boune-compatible shell, not tcsh (which is /bin/tcsh). A start would be something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
for pid in $(pgrep <process name>); do kill -HUP $pid; done
```

Without more details, I can't really say much more.

Comment: WOW, so simple.  I changed the -HUP to -9 to test.  Wham, both parent and child processes stopped.  Thanks - Brad

Comment: If there's nothing else you want to do in the body of the loop, you can also write it as

    pgrep <process name> | xargs kill -HUP

Comment: Yeh, I knew a pipe was needed somehow.  Thanks again - Brad